# Database integrity issue with multi-table inheritance in django

Tags: django-models

Here are the relevant models:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    objects = InheritanceManager()

    game = models.ForeignKey(Game)
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['time']

class ShipMoveEvent(Event):
    objects = InheritanceManager()

    ship = models.ForeignKey(Ship)
    space = space(null=True, blank=True)

class DepthChargeEvent(ShipMoveEvent):
    target = space()
    nearMiss = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    hit = models.ForeignKey(Sub, blank=True, null=True)
```

I can create a ShipMoveEvent fine. When I go to create the DepthChargeEvent, I get this error on save:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: sub_search_depthchargeevent.event_ptr_id
```

Any ideas why? I am stumped. It obviously has something to do with django's multi-table inheritance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that this is a bug in the sqlite database binding. I switched to postgresql and have not had this problem since.